# Find array value starting with some text

Tags: jquery

I have some dynamically generated form fields and i have used jquery array serialize and i got this data after posting

```
results_English  ::-value  10
results_Science  ::-value  20
results_Geography  ::-value  30
results_History  ::-value  40
results_Drawing  ::-value  50
results_Architecture  ::-value  60
```

I have used this code

```
var dataArray = $('#er').serializeArray();
       len = dataArray.length,
       dataObj = {};

    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
    console.log(dataArray[i].name+"  ::-value  "+dataArray[i].value);
    var arr = dataArray[i].name;
    };
```

I am trying to get the fields that start with `results_` and the value after `_` becomes the new key of an a new array but the value remains.

To get starting,i am tryin grep

```
var r = jQuery.grep(arr, function(a){
    return a == 'results_'
    }).length;
```

but its returning `0`.

How can i find the values startin with results_ and use the part after _to create a new array?.

Comment: Very clear that none of the keys are `==` to `'results_'` ... try using `indexOf()`

Answer (score 0):

You say "fields that start with" but you are checking the exact matches. Also you have an array of objects, so the `a` is an object not a string. You should check the `name` property of the object.

```
var r = jQuery.grep(arr, function(a) {
    return a.name.indexOf('results_') === 0;
}).length;
```

Comment: indexof is undefined,thats what i am getting as an error.

Comment: Note that JavaScript is case-sensitive. The method name is `indexOf` not `indexof`.